# Loading the CNN model and predict the CSV file

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm learning the basic CNN model by using tensorflow. After training my model, I want to load it and use the model to predict the hand-written digital img (CSV file).

Here is my CNN model:

```
import random
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)


class CNNLogisticClassification:

    def __init__(self, shape_picture, n_labels,
                 learning_rate=0.5, dropout_ratio=0.5, alpha=0.0):
        self.shape_picture = shape_picture
        self.n_labels = n_labels

        self.weights = None
        self.biases = None

        self.graph = tf.Graph()  # initialize new grap
        self.build(learning_rate, dropout_ratio, alpha)  # building graph

        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)  # create session by the graph


    def build(self, learning_rate, dropout_ratio, alpha):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            ### Input
            self.train_pictures = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                                 shape=[None]+self.shape_picture,name="Input")
            self.train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                               shape=(None, self.n_labels),name="Output")

            ### Optimalization
            # build neurel network structure and get their predictions and loss
            self.y_, self.original_loss = self.structure(pictures=self.train_pictures,
                                                         labels=self.train_labels,
                                                         dropout_ratio=dropout_ratio,
                                                         train=True, )
            # regularization loss
            self.regularization = \
                tf.reduce_sum([tf.nn.l2_loss(w) for w in self.weights.values()]) \
                / tf.reduce_sum([tf.size(w, out_type=tf.float32) for w in self.weights.values()])

            # total loss
            self.loss = self.original_loss + alpha * self.regularization

            # define training operation
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
            self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss)

            ### Prediction
            self.new_pictures = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                               shape=[None]+self.shape_picture,name="Input")
            self.new_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                             shape=(None, self.n_labels),name="Output")
            self.new_y_, self.new_original_loss = self.structure(pictures=self.new_pictures,
                                                                 labels=self.new_labels)
            self.new_loss = self.new_original_loss + alpha * self.regularization

            ### Initialization
            self.init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

            ### save model
            self.saver=tf.train.Saver()



    def structure(self, pictures, labels, dropout_ratio=None, train=False):
        ### Variable
        ## LeNet5 Architecture(http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/)
        # input:(batch,28,28,1) => conv1[5x5,6] => (batch,24,24,6)
        # pool2 => (batch,12,12,6) => conv2[5x5,16] => (batch,8,8,16)
        # pool4 => fatten5 => (batch,4x4x16) => fc6 => (batch,120)
        # (batch,120) => fc7 => (batch,84)
        # (batch,84) => fc8 => (batch,10) => softmax

        if (not self.weights) and (not self.biases):
            self.weights = {
                'conv1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 1, 6),
                                                         stddev=0.1)),
                'conv3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 6, 16),
                                                         stddev=0.1)),
                'fc6': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(4*4*16, 120),
                                                       stddev=0.1)),
                'fc7': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(120, 84),
                                                       stddev=0.1)),
                'fc8': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(84, self.n_labels),
                                                       stddev=0.1)),
            }
            self.biases = {
                'conv1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(6))),
                'conv3': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(16))),
                'fc6': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(120))),
                'fc7': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(84))),
                'fc8': tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(self.n_labels))),
            }

        ### Structure
        conv1 = self.get_conv_2d_layer(pictures,
                                       self.weights['conv1'], self.biases['conv1'],
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')
        conv3 = self.get_conv_2d_layer(pool2,
                                       self.weights['conv3'], self.biases['conv3'],
                                       activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')
        fatten5 = self.get_flatten_layer(pool4)

        if train:
            fatten5 = tf.nn.dropout(fatten5, keep_prob=1-dropout_ratio[0])

        fc6 = self.get_dense_layer(fatten5,
                                   self.weights['fc6'], self.biases['fc6'],
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu)

        if train:
            fc6 = tf.nn.dropout(fc6, keep_prob=1-dropout_ratio[1])

        fc7 = self.get_dense_layer(fc6,
                                   self.weights['fc7'], self.biases['fc7'],
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu)

        logits = self.get_dense_layer(fc7, self.weights['fc8'], self.biases['fc8'])

        y_ = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                 tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,
                                                         logits=logits))

        return (y_, loss)


    def get_dense_layer(self, input_layer, weight, bias, activation=None):
        x = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer, weight), bias)
        if activation:
            x = activation(x)
        return x

    def get_conv_2d_layer(self, input_layer,
                          weight, bias,
                          strides=(1, 1), padding='VALID', activation=None):
        x = tf.add(
              tf.nn.conv2d(input_layer,
                           weight,
                           [1, strides[0], strides[1], 1],
                           padding=padding), bias)
        if activation:
            x = activation(x)
        return x

    def get_flatten_layer(self, input_layer):
        shape = input_layer.get_shape().as_list()
        n = 1
        for s in shape[1:]:
            n *= s
        x = tf.reshape(input_layer, [-1, n])
        return x

    def fit(self, X, y, epochs=10,
            validation_data=None, test_data=None, batch_size=None):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        y = self._check_array(y)

        N = X.shape[0]
        random.seed(9000)
        if not batch_size:
            batch_size = N

        self.sess.run(self.init_op)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            print('Epoch %2d/%2d: ' % (epoch+1, epochs))

            # mini-batch gradient descent
            index = [i for i in range(N)]
            random.shuffle(index)
            while len(index) > 0:
                index_size = len(index)
                batch_index = [index.pop() for _ in range(min(batch_size, index_size))]

                feed_dict = {
                    self.train_pictures: X[batch_index, :],
                    self.train_labels: y[batch_index],
                }
                _, loss = self.sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss],
                                        feed_dict=feed_dict)

                print('[%d/%d] loss = %.4f     ' % (N-len(index), N, loss), end='\r')

            # evaluate at the end of this epoch
            y_ = self.predict(X)
            train_loss = self.evaluate(X, y)
            train_acc = self.accuracy(y_, y)
            msg = '[%d/%d] loss = %8.4f, acc = %3.2f%%' % (N, N, train_loss, train_acc*100)

            if validation_data:
                val_loss = self.evaluate(validation_data[0], validation_data[1])
                val_acc = self.accuracy(self.predict(validation_data[0]), validation_data[1])
                msg += ', val_loss = %8.4f, val_acc = %3.2f%%' % (val_loss, val_acc*100)

            print(msg)

        if test_data:
            test_acc = self.accuracy(self.predict(test_data[0]), test_data[1])
            print('test_acc = %3.2f%%' % (test_acc*100))



    def accuracy(self, predictions, labels):
        return (np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))/predictions.shape[0])

    def predict(self, X):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        return self.sess.run(self.new_y_, feed_dict={self.new_pictures: X})

    def evaluate(self, X, y):
        X = self._check_array(X)
        y = self._check_array(y)
        return self.sess.run(self.new_loss, feed_dict={self.new_pictures: X,
                                                       self.new_labels: y})

    def _check_array(self, ndarray):
        ndarray = np.array(ndarray)
        if len(ndarray.shape) == 1:
            ndarray = np.reshape(ndarray, (1, ndarray.shape[0]))
        return ndarray


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Extract MNIST Dataset ...')

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)

    train_data = mnist.train
    valid_data = mnist.validation
    test_data = mnist.test

    train_img = np.reshape(train_data.images, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    valid_img = np.reshape(valid_data.images, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    test_img = np.reshape(test_data.images, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    model = CNNLogisticClassification(
        shape_picture=[28, 28, 1],
        n_labels=10,
        learning_rate=0.07,
        dropout_ratio=[0.2, 0.1],
        alpha=0.1,
    )


    model.fit(
        X=train_img,
        y=train_data.labels,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=(valid_img, valid_data.labels),
        test_data=(test_img, test_data.labels),
        batch_size=32,
    )
    saver = model.saver.save(model.sess, "test_model")
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % saver)
```

And I create another py file to load my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model/test_model.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model/test_model.meta') 
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./my_model')) 

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver.predict('D:\python\number_data\3.csv')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'Saver' object has no attribute 'predict'

How do I fix it and let the trained model predict my CSV file?
Thanks in advance for your help!

## Edit:

I change my second py file as below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

X=pd.read_csv('D:/PYTHON/cnn_data/7.csv', index_col=None, header=None).values
X1=X/255
X3=tf.convert_to_tensor(
    X1,
    dtype=None,
    dtype_hint=None,
    name=None
)


saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model/test_model.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model/test_model.meta') 
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./my_model')) 
    graph=tf.get_default_graph()
    xs0=graph.get_tensor_by_name("Input:0")
    prediction=graph.get_tensor_by_name("Output:0")

    sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={xs0:X3})
    print(prediction)
```

I only try to predict one digital img data(CSV file with one row), I transfer it into tensor type and name my two placeholder "Input" , "Output", but get another error:

> TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1, 784), dtype=float64) which was passed to 
>   the feed with key Tensor("Input:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32).

>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the obvious error here is that you are trying to call a function that doesn't exist. Evidently, the saver object does not have a predict function.

Second, if you want Tensorflow to make predictions, you need to provide it with "Tensorflow" input, and sadly, CSVs are not one of them.

All you need to do is transform your CSV inputs into tensors, with a function like this for instance:

```py
filename = 'D:\python\number_data\3.csv'

def csv_to_tensor(filename):

    ...

    return tensors
```

I cannot tell you how to implement the function exactly since I don't know the exact format of your data, but I am assuming that each row in your file is an input. So you most likely just need to loop through the lines in your file and convert each line to a tensor, which can then be used by a Tensorflow model.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I try to transfer my CSV file into a tensor type, but get another error, I don't know how to change my feed into a dictionary type.